# Looking for vba to export records in excel for searched result in Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-excel

MY search record sql.

```
sql = "SELECT VIN_History.[Record _ID], VIN_History.PhysicalVIN, VIN_History.LogicalVIN, VIN_History.VERSION, VIN_History.BODY_STYLE, VIN_History.ENGINE_TYPES, VIN_History.BODY_EXTERIOR_COLOR, VIN_History.INDIA_OR_EXPORT, VIN_History.DRIVE_TYPES, VIN_History.TRANSMISSION_TYPES, VIN_History.FUEL_TYPE, VIN_History.MARKET, VIN_History.MARKET_CATEGORY " _
     & "FROM [VIN_History] WHERE(((VIN_History.BODY_STYLE) In (" & Strsearch1 & ")) AND ((VIN_History.DRIVE_TYPES) In (" & Strsearch & ")) AND ((VIN_History.FUEL_TYPE) In (" & Strsearch2 & ")) AND ((VIN_History.MARKET_CATEGORY) In (" & Strsearch3 & ")))"

Me.SbfRecord.Form.RecordSource = sql
Me.SbfRecord.Form.Requery
```

I want to export sql result in  Form with export CMD.

[image: Results]

Comment: ui my solution isnt working please add content to as to why not

Answer (score 0):

```
 DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "yourformname", acFormatXLS, _
"C:\path\toyourfile\yourfile.xls"
```

This exports the forms data to excel.